# Count the number of times a value/string is in a column when other columns are filtered

Tags: microsoft-excel, countif

I am trying to count the number of times a value/string is in a column when other columns are filtered.

Example: I want to be able to filter any column, A through V, and then count how many times a cell value exists in Column X after the filter is applied.

Count of values in the remaining cells, not the number of remaining cells.

Comment: What type of file are you trying to do this on.  An excel file, a text file...what?

Answer (score 1):

Use `=Subtotal(9, <your range to sum>)` to accomplish this. `Subtotal(9,<range>)` only sums up numbers in the specified range that are not hidden. Since you are wanting to get a count, then just make a column where the value is "1" for every row, and use that as your range.

Comment: surely with subtotal, function 109 is ignore hidden values and function 9 include hidden values and filtered-out cells are always excluded anyway